# Highest power of two but smaller than given BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

I need to find highest power of two but smaller than given BigInteger. I have written following method for the same and it works, just wondering does better solution or even different solution exists?

```
 private static BigInteger getHighestPowerOf2(BigInteger bigInteger)
    {
    int bitLength = bigInteger.bitLength();
    for (int index = 0; index < (bitLength - 1); index++)
        bigInteger = bigInteger.clearBit(index);
    return bigInteger;
    }
```

As I am dealing which large number which exceeds limit of long and int so I cannot use & operator.
I am using Java 7.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using setBit to set one bit instead of clearing a lot of bits?

```
private static BigInteger getHighestPowerOf2(BigInteger bigInteger)
{
   int bitLength = bigInteger.bitLength();
   return BigInteger.ZERO.setBit(bitLength-1);
}
```